# Raise_application_error() does stop execution ? (Stop inserting/delete/update in table)

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql, triggers

Raise_application_error() With "Before Delete" Trigger can prevent and stop the delete from the table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [*raise_application_error*](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/errors.htm#i3329) can prevent and stop delete. Consider the following example :

```
SQL> desc emp
Name     Type         Nullable Default Comments 
-------- ------------ -------- ------- -------- 
EMPNO    NUMBER(4)                              
ENAME    VARCHAR2(10) Y                         
JOB      VARCHAR2(9)  Y                         
MGR      NUMBER(4)    Y                         
HIREDATE DATE         Y                         
SAL      NUMBER(7,2)  Y                         
COMM     NUMBER(7,2)  Y                         
DEPTNO   NUMBER(2)    Y 

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_del_emp
  2    before delete on emp
  3    for each row
  4  declare
  5  begin
  6    if ( :old.deptno = 10 ) then
  7     raise_application_error(-20222,'Records with Deptno=10 can not be deleted!');
  8    end if;
  9  end;
 10  /

Trigger created

SQL> insert all
  2         into emp values(7782,'CLARK','MANAGER',7839,  date'1981-06-09',2450.00,null,10)
  3         into emp values(7788,'SCOTT','ANALYST',7566,  date'1987-04-19',3000.00,null,20)
  4  select * from dual;

2 rows inserted

SQL> delete emp where empno = 7782;

delete emp where empno = 7782

ORA-20222: Records with Deptno=10 can not be deleted
ORA-06512: at "HR.TRG_DEL_EMP", line 4
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'HR.TRG_DEL_EMP'

SQL> delete emp where empno = 7788;

1 row deleted

SQL> rollback;

Rollback complete
```

Comment: Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will "stop execution". From [Using Triggers](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm):

> ## Error Conditions and Exceptions in the Trigger Body
>
> **If a predefined or user-defined error condition (exception) is raised during the execution of a trigger body, then all effects of the trigger body, as well as the triggering statement, are rolled back (unless the error is trapped by an exception handler).**
>
> **Therefore, a trigger body can prevent the execution of the triggering statement by raising an exception.**

Comment: Thanks for your help !